# Must run within a Fiber error when using NPM package in Meteor.js

Tags: meteor

I'm using NPM OAuth library because I can't get Meteor's to work.  I get this error.

Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.

It works if I remove the Collection.upsert line.

```
var OAuth = Meteor.require('oauth').OAuth;

var oa = new OAuth(null, null, consumer_key, consumer_secret, "1.0", null, "HMAC-SHA1");

var request = oa.post("https://stream.api.com/blah.json", access_token, access_secret);

request.on('response', function (response) {
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function(data) {
        var j = JSON.parse(data)
        Collection.upsert({symbol: j.symbol}, {last: j.last})
    })
});

request.end();
```

I've read about Meteor.bindEnvironment and Meteor._wrapAsync but can't get it to work.

Comment: What is happening when you try to use Meteor's authentication?

Comment: I get invalid signature when passing variables in the url.  http://api.com/blah.json?symbols=AAPL.  Works fine with NPM Oauth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Collection.upsert` method works when embedded within a Fiber, while your callback for `request.on` is called arbitrarily, not wrapped with one. Try this:

```
request.on('response', function (response) {
    new Fiber(function(){
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.on('data', function(data) {
            var j = JSON.parse(data)
            Collection.upsert({symbol: j.symbol}, {last: j.last})
        });
    }).run();
});
```